# TurboGears2.2.0 install/run error when nosetests and paster setup-app development.ini

Tags: python, turbogears, paster, turbogears2

I encountered a problem after I finished all process of installing TurboGear2 on my OS X 10.8.2.
Using Python2.7, TurboGear2.2.0
The installing process was based on tutorial of official website: http://www.turbogears.org/2.2/docs/main/DownloadInstall.html

Problem describing:
1. Follow the tutorial, installation went smoothly until nosetests show 10 ERRORs.
2. Then, "paster setup-app development.ini" also show error messages as below:
[image]

But I command "paster serve development.ini" in terminal, the server still successfully work.

I think there're some problems, but I found no answers.
Do anyone have any idea about this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah unfortunatly that's a problem with the new version of sqlalchemy... just remove the version of sqlalchemy `pip uninstall sqlalchemy` and install the 0.7.9 version `pip install sqlalchemy==0.7.9`

Comment: If you want to have a future-prove setup.py dependency list, I suggest you write something like `sqlalchemy <= 0.799` in there.